# Exception while removing the items from android listview

Tags: android, listview, exception

I created a listview with content and used delete button for each row. Here I tried to remove the items from the listview by using it's delete button.while deleting  final element of list view ,throws ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception.

I googled and findout few solutions like:

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {

        return lsit.size();
    }
```

and `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

but none of the solutions won't solves my problem.

Here is my code:

```
public View getView( final int position, View convertView,final ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        System.out.println("saved homes list..");
        System.out.println("Position: "+m_itemClickedPosition_savedHomes);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.nearbyhomestext, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.homeTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
            holder.homePlan = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_plan);
            holder.deleteButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);


            holder.activeDrawable = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_bg_hover);
            holder.inActiveDrawable = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_bg);
            holder.deleteButton.setTag(position);
            //holder.deleteButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(
                    new Button.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            System.out.println("Clicked position:"+position);
                            System.out.println("ArraySize:"+m_savedHomesList.size());
                          //Integer index = (Integer) v.getTag();
                              m_savedHomesList.remove(position); 
                              m_savedHomesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                );
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }   


        return convertView;
    }
```

LogCatError:

```
    07-25 14:25:56.187: E/AndroidRuntime(5152): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 14:25:56.187: E/AndroidRuntime(5152): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
07-25 14:25:56.187: E/AndroidRuntime(5152):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
07-25 14:25:56.187: E/AndroidRuntime(5152):     at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:406)
07-25 14:25:56.187: E/AndroidRuntime(5152):     at com.cpt.realtor.tablet.fragments.HomeListFragment$SavedHomeBaseAdapter$1.onClick(HomeListFragment.java:399)
07-25 14:25:56.187: E/AndroidRuntime(5152):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
07-25 14:25:56.187: E/AndroidRuntime(5152):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
07-25 14:25:56.187: E/AndroidRuntime(5152):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-25 14:25:56.187: E/AndroidRuntime(5152):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-25 14:25:56.187: E/AndroidRuntime(5152):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-25 14:25:56.187: E/AndroidRuntime(5152):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
07-25 14:25:56.187: E/AndroidRuntime(5152):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 14:25:56.187: E/AndroidRuntime(5152):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-25 14:25:56.187: E/AndroidRuntime(5152):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
07-25 14:25:56.187: E/AndroidRuntime(5152):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
07-25 14:25:56.187: E/AndroidRuntime(5152):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Need help to solve this..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: index 1, size is 1 => The size of the list is "1" so it looks like this : [0] you are trying to delete the second cell [0][1] which doen't exist

Comment: ListView's positions are zero based too. Then why `position-1` ?

Comment: @S.D: I tried with position on the place of position-1.Result still same

Comment: hey your adapter accesses m_villages, but you are trying to remove an element from m_savedHomesList.. Instead of giving partial code, give complete code of your adapter. then only others can findout whts the problem.

Comment: You have to put the Click Listener before "return convertView;"

Comment: Hey..Thanks @Akram it's sloved.. But, why data not deleted from my DB. I used notifyDataSetChanged(). When I came from previous activity, deleted items are still shown on my listview.

Comment: @Lokesh you deleted the data from the list available in the adapter and not from the list available in activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public int getCount() {
    return m_savedHomesList.size();
}
```

you are removing from m_savedHomesList in getView(..) function. So the adapter should be based on m_savedHomesList.
Also in getView method, just use

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

instead of m_savedHomesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @ Akram Fares: So, I need to create any method to remove data from DB?

Comment: I created an answer for your question

Answer (score 0):

For the `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` answer is to put the listener before the `return convertView;` & the `notifyDataSetChanged();` you have to create a handler :

```
public View getView( final int position, View convertView,final ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    System.out.println("saved homes list..");
    System.out.println("Position: "+m_itemClickedPosition_savedHomes);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.nearbyhomestext, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.homeTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
        holder.homePlan = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_plan);
        holder.deleteButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);


        holder.activeDrawable = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_bg_hover);
        holder.inActiveDrawable = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_bg);
        holder.deleteButton.setTag(position);
        //holder.deleteButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }   
    // Your listener here
    holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        System.out.println("Clicked position:"+position);
                        System.out.println("ArraySize:"+m_savedHomesList.size());
                      //Integer index = (Integer) v.getTag();
                          m_savedHomesList.remove(position); 
                          mHandler.setEmptyMessage(0);
                    }
                }
            );

    mHandler =  new Handler() { // Don't forget to declare your handler
     public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
    };

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Good to know that you overcame the problem and its resolved

Anyway i would suggest you to use a different approach as it would be more correct (just a suggestion do think over though)

- Set an interface in the adapter which is implemented by the activity.
- Send callback to activity when the delete btn is clicked with the position of the item to be deleted.
- In the callback received in the activity (the position is also received there) Update the arrayList passed to the adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged()